# Devise + Facebook + Omniauth callback stuck

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise + Rails 3. These are the gems I'm using:

```
gem 'devise' (1.3.4)
gem 'mm-devise' (1.2)
gem 'omniauth-facebook' (1.3.0)
gem 'omniauth' (1.1.0)
gem 'oauth2' (0.6.1)
gem 'oa-core' (0.3.2)
```

I followed the [setup tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) on devise/omniauth wiki.

```
My routes:

devise_for :users
resources :events
resources :posts
resources :users
root :to => "home#index"

devise_scope :user do
  get "sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Facebook redirects me to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback.
```

I see the request being stuck in Pending mode on the browser. The server log shows:

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
```

but never passes this phase. I set up the callback as suggested in the tutorial:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    ...
  end

  def passthru
    ...
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking if there was a failure

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def failure
    debugger
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem coming from the JS SDK when using it on port 3000.
Try running your local server on a standard port.

```
sudo rails s -p 80* or *rvmsudo rails s -p 80
```

Answer (score 0):

How are your firewall settings? I had that exact issue when ports 32768 to 61000 were not open. Suffered that for a long time after smart people in Superuser.com told me what is happening. https://superuser.com/questions/479503/why-are-ports-30000-to-60000-needed-when-browsing-the-net